# How do I disable whatever Intelisense is showing me components when I start an open brace in JavaScript?

Tags: vs-code

When I type `@api showModal() {` in VS Code, I get this from Intelisense:

[image]

If I press the return key, as I normally will to create a new line, the first item gets selected instead of a carriage return.

I'm *never* going to want those items to be available when I open a brace. How can I turn off this "feature?"

VS Code 1.65.0, Salesforce Extension Pack 54.4.0.

Comment: Not a solution, but a temporary habit to get in to is to just tap Esc when you do that. If no intellisense pops up, nothing happens, but if it does, it'll be closed. Aside from that, I'd recommend opening up an issue on the extension repository. I don't think there's an option to prevent this now, and it definitely feels like a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's the solution. Uncheck the "Show Folders" setting. No idea why it's trying to show me folders there. It does seem to be a bug, and I opened an [issue](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/3902) on it.

[image]

Comment: Excellent. I look forward to seeing this fixed. This has been irritating me for a while now.

Answer (score 2):

Set the completion hotkey to <kbd>tab</kbd> instead of <kbd>return</kbd>!

Then you can press <kbd>return</kbd> without being hindered by the barrage of options

See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911977/prevent-autocomplete-in-visual-studio-code